# Spring security handle PreAuthenticatedCredentialsNotFoundException to yield 403 or 401

Tags: exception, spring-security

I am using `[RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter][1]` and let it throw `PreAuthenticatedCredentialsNotFoundException` if header is not set. My problem is that this yields a 500 status.

How to handle `PreAuthenticatedCredentialsNotFoundException` that it returns the 401 or 403 error response?

Comment: of course, but in this case there is no exception at all. with fals i have to throw an exception - but which one?

Comment: You are using the wrong filter. `RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter` is for preauthentication, it isn't for authentication. It assumes you already logged in. So you can't say, that the user isn't authenticated.

Comment: your are right, but i want to say it - or the other way around i want to control the http status returned for specific exceptions thrown.